# Why is the Computer Clock faster than the real clock

Tags: time

Using the conventional way of measuring run time, I've done something like the following:

```
start = time.time()

#example code
for _ in range(100000):
   for __ in range(100000):
       print(_)

end = time.time()
run_time = end-start
```

I noticed in some cases, the run_time reading would give me 9 seconds. But I was 100% sure it hasn't been 9 seconds long. So I measured with my phone stopwatch. Conservatively speaking, I got 2 seconds on my phone's stopwatch while the program says 4 seconds. (and I have done this multiple times to check it wasn't a false reading) So now I am wondering if the computer's clock works in a different way than our *normal* clock.

Comment: well, what is "my prog?"  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: it's a simple nested for loop

Comment: Show your actual code. Don't say "I've done something like the following". Your example doesn't output the time, so is presumably not what you are actually running.